# Swift: Call some method after object initialized in protocol extension

Tags: swift, oop, swift2, swift-protocols

Let's say I have structure:

```
class A: UIViewController {

}

class C {
}

class B: A, P {
    typealias T = C
}

protocol P: class {
    typealias T
}

extension P {
    func initP() {
        print("test")
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call initP without modifying B? Anything else may be modified. 
I'm trying to create something like generic abstract class. System (A ,P) is Base. (B, C) -- Concrete implementation. Method initP is exactly same for all implementations. That's why I'm trying to avoid calling it in implantations. On the other hand it uses methods and types from P. That's why I cannot simply call it in A. 
First of all I tried to make A generic but in this case App crashes in runtime if B is passed as class of the scene in storyboard

Comment: As given, your first block of code won't compile since `initialize` is a class function and `initP` is an instance function, hence `initialize` can't invoke `initP`

Comment: Agreed. It was hard day and I missed that it's static. However is it possible to call initP from the second block with given restrictions?

Comment: I've modified the question to show my real issue.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're wanting to call `initP`

Comment: When class B is instantiated. Actually it's acceptable if it will be called on viewDidLoad or any other UiViewController life cycle method.

Comment: This is not possible. I believe what you want is aspect programming and that's not possible for Swift (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't this work for you:

```
extension P {
    init() { // Or initWithCoder since it's a ViewController?
        print("test")
        self.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be able to try this only tomorrow. But the problem is that P doesn't know, that it will be applied to subclass of UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used a protocol extension to define `initP` that function will be available any time an object is known to implement the protocol.

```
B().initP()

let b:B
b.initP()

class C : P {
    init() {
        initP()
    }
}

class B: A, P {
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        initP()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initP()
    }
}
```

are all valid.

Comment: I'm trying to create something like generic abstract class. System <A ,P> is Base. <B, C> -- Concrete implementation. Method callP is exactly same for all implementations. That's why I'm trying to avoid calling it in implantations. On the other hand it uses methods and types from P. That's why I cannot simply call it in A.

Comment: So callP is the same for all implementations and calls initP, but initP is specific to each implementation?

Comment: It's generic but completely same. Something like initP = { print(T) }

Comment: Sorry It's late night and I make mistakes. CallP and initP are same thing